# How to show "Formal Title" on the view Contact screen?

Tags: contacts, fields, summaryfields

A previous developer repurposed the "formal title" field to be used as "badge name" for events.

The problem is that when viewing a contact, it doesn't show there unless you go to *edit* the name.

I found a "recipe" for displaying formal title as part of the general display of names, but that is not what we want.

How can we 1. display the "formal title" field when viewing a contact, but 2. *not* display it as part of a name everywhere that a name is displayed?

Comment: Have a look at the screenshot here: https://gist.github.com/mecachisenros/785d9d8eef15359b4f66a332406b7b0e  that appends an id to the contact name in the Contact Summary but you can append pretty much anything and is a fairly easy customization, I'm just wondering if something like that would work for you, if it does I'll add an answer with instructions.

Comment: Something like that could work - we may have to use some conditionals to show it only in certain places, mainly when viewing a contact as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @coleman says and as I also mentioned in my comment above, you can create an extension as explained [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) or you can use an existing one and implement  `hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname`, somthing like this:

```
function myextension_civicrm_contact_get_displayname(&$display_name, $contactId, $objContact) {
    $formal_title = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', array(
        'sequential' => 1,
        'contact_id' => $contactId,
        'return' => 'formal_title',
    ));
    if(!$formal_title['is_error'] && !empty($formal_title['formal_title'])){
        $display_name = $display_name . ' - Formal Title: ' . $formal_title['formal_title'];
    } else {
        $display_name = $display_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname). This allows you to alter the display name of a contact when it appears in the UI (namely in the contact summary screen and a few other screens where the display name is used as a title) without changing it in the db.